# Error in SQL syntax, check the manual

Tags: mysql, borland-c++

I'm using MySQL Control Center to test some SQL statements that are throwing an error in my code.  Every time I test it doesn't give any feedback on what the error is, where the error is.  It just lists the whole statement and says it's somewhere in there.  This is the statement, as it is in Borland, that's giving me an error:

```
sprintf(sql, "CREATE TABLE %s AS "
               "SELECT "
               " LPAD(V0_X1_A3, 13, ' ') AS V0_X1_A3, "
               " SUM (F5*F6) AS CostExt, "
               " IFNULL(V0_X1_A2, 0.00000) AS V0_X1_A2, "
               " SUM(F6) AS F6 "
               "FROM _TransRecords "
               " LEFT OUTER JOIN _V0_X1 ON V0_X1_PK = V0_X1_FK "
               "WHERE %s "
               " GROUP BY V0_X1_A3 ", TblName, where);
```

I edited the syntax to read as:

```
sprintf(sql, "CREATE TABLE %s AS "
               " SELECT "
               " SUM (F5*F6) AS CostExt, "
               " SUM(F6) AS F6 "
               " FROM _TransRecords "
               " LPAD(V0_X1_A3, 13, ' ') AS V0_X1_A3, "
               " IFNULL(V0_X1_A2, 0.00000) AS V0_X1_A2, "
               " FROM _V0_X1 "
               " LEFT OUTER JOIN _V0_X1 ON V0_X1_PK = V0_X1_FK "
               " WHERE %s "
               " GROUP BY V0_X1_A3 ", TblName, where);
```

Comment: show the actual generated statement, where the %s placeholders have been filled in.

Comment: what do you put instead of the `%s` placeholders?

Comment: no that's what I put.  One second.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in the `JOIN` syntax since you don't specify the table names in the `ON` condition.
I'm guessing a solution (since I don't know which columns belong to which table):

```
           "CREATE TABLE %s AS "
           "SELECT "
           " LPAD(V0_X1_A3, 13, ' ') AS V0_X1_A3, "
           " SUM (F5*F6) AS CostExt, "
           " IFNULL(V0_X1_A2, 0.00000) AS V0_X1_A2, "
           " SUM(F6) AS F6 "
           "FROM _TransRecords "
           " LEFT OUTER JOIN _V0_X1 ON _TransRecords.V0_X1_PK = _V0_X1.V0_X1_FK "
           "WHERE %s "
           " GROUP BY V0_X1_A3 "
```

Comment: I used what you recommended and _V0_X1.V0_X1_PK and neither of them worked.

Comment: Can you give some more explaination on the tables structure and on the relations between them?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.  Here's my code.

```
sprintf(sql, "CREATE TABLE %s AS "
               " SELECT "
               " SUM(F5*F6) AS CostExt, "
               " SUM(F6) AS F6, "
               " LPAD(V0_X1_A3, 13, ' ') AS V0_X1_A3, "
               " IFNULL(V0_X1_A2, 0.00000) AS V0_X1_A2, "
               " SUM(V0_X1_A2*F6) AS RetailExt "
               " FROM _TransRecords "
               " LEFT OUTER JOIN _V0_X1 ON V0_X1_PK = V0_X1_FK "
               " WHERE %s "
               " GROUP BY V0_X1_A3 ", TblName, where);
```